# Отправка фалов form на сервер через Ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

Здравствуйте. У меня такая проблема, есть форма html в ней определенные поля. Когда отправляю данные, то данные всех полей отправляются, кроме поля где передается файл. Только начал изучать ajax. Прошу помогите.

**Форма HTML**

```
<form method="post" id="add" name="add" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row form-field">
        <label class="col-lg-2" for="logo">Добавить лого</label>
        <input class="col-lg-5" type="file" id="logo" name="logo">
    </div>

    <div class="row form-field">
        <label class="col-lg-2" for="name-shop">Название магазина</label>
        <input class="col-lg-5" type="text" id="name-shop" name="name-shop">
    </div>

    <div class="row form-field">
        <label class="col-lg-2" for="description">Описание магазина</label>
        <textarea class="col-lg-5" id="description" name="description" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="row form-field">
        <label class="col-lg-2" for="date-create">Дата создания</label>
        <input class="col-lg-5" type="text" id="date-create" name="date-create">
    </div>

    <input type="button" name="btn_add" id="btn_add" value="Добавить">
</form>
```

**Обработчик PHP**

```
 $name_shop   = $_POST['name-shop'];
 $description = $_POST['description'];
 $description = $_POST['description'];
 $date        = $_POST['date-create'];
 $logo        = $_FILES['logo'];
 $logo_path   = upload_logo( $logo );

 if ( isset( $name_shop ) && isset( $description ) && isset( $date ) ) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO shops (logo, name_shop, description, date_create)". 
             "VALUES ('$logo_path', '$name_shop', '$description', '$date')";
    $res   = array(
        'name_shop'   => $name_shop,
        'description' => $description,
        'date'        => $date,
        'logo_path'   => $logo_path
    );

    // Переводим массив в JSON
    echo json_encode( $res );
 }

function upload_logo( $logo ) {
    $upload_dir = 'img/';
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['logo']['tmp_name'];
    if ( move_uploaded_file( $tmp_name, $upload_dir . $logo['name'] ) ) {
        return realpath( $upload_dir . $logo['name'] );
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Ajax.js код**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn_add").click(function () {
        sendAjaxForm('add', '../php/set_data.php');
        return false;
    });
});

function sendAjaxForm(ajax_form, url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text',
        data: $("#" + ajax_form).serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
            var result = $.parseJSON(response);
            if (result.name_shop === '') {
                 alert("Заполните поле ");
            } else if (result.description === '') {
                 alert("Заполните поле 'Описание магазина'");
            } else if (result.date === '') {
                 alert("Заполните поле 'Дата открытия магазина'");
            } else {
                 alert("Магазин '" + result.name_shop + "' успешно добавлен");
                 location.reload(true);
            }
        },
        error: function () { // Данные не отправлены
            alert('Ошибка. Данные не отправлены.');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$().serialize()` не включает данные файлов. Используйте `FormData`.

```
    data: new FormData($("#" + ajax_form)[0]),
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData